# Unable to Consume simple ASP.NET web service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

As a practice exercise, I've published a (very simple) web service,

http://www.myshoptour.com/WebServices/HelloWorldMST.asmx

The test page works great, but I am having problems consuming it in my website. My code is as follows:

```
Try
    Dim wsProd As New wsHelloWorldMSTprod.HelloWorldMSTSoapClient()
    wsProd.Open()
    Select Case rblSelectHelloWorldType.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            strOut = wsProd.HelloWorld1()
        Case 1
            strOut = wsProd.HelloWorld2()
        Case Else
    End Select
    wsProd.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

The line with the "new" seems to be the problem. It does nothing. Seems like it does not return. I am unable to trace into it.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong (and show me the correct code)?

Thanks in advance. And sorry if this is in the wrong category - it has been a while since I've posted here. I'm getting back into web development after a much needed break!

Edit:

woodykiddy... thank you so much! I got it to work. The only significant difference:

Originally:
Dim wsProd As New wsHelloWorldMSTprod.HelloWorldMSTSoapClient()

Fix:
Dim wsProd As New wsHelloWorldMSTprod.HelloWorldMSTSoapClient("HelloWorldMSTSo‌​ap")

Thanks again!

Comment: Do you get an error of some sort when you try to run this code, or does it just not work? And how do you know the line with the `New` does nothing?

Comment: When I trace, both stepping into, and stepping over, the line with the new, it just does nothing / does not work.  Same without tracing, no response from web service.

Comment: This is so frustrating because it is the simplest web service.  As I said, I am doing this as an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did to consume your web service in my application. I hope you will find this sample helpful.

**Steps that I followed**

1. Right-click my VS project to add **Service Reference**
2. In the Service Reference Settings, add "http://www.myshoptour.com/WebServices/HelloWorldMST.asmx" to the Address field
3. Click Go/Discover and Visual Studio should start pulling service info into your project and configuring the settings, like service endpoints, etc. Once it's done, you can call your Service Methods in your application code. Also, a new folder, **Service References** will be automatically created by VS, if previously wasn't created.
4. Add a Test web page and put a Drop down list control and a Label control on it
5. Consume web service in the code behind

**Test Page Markup**

```
<div>
Web Service Methods:
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
 <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="HelloWorld1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="HelloWorld2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div>
    Web Service Response:
    <br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
</div>
```

**Test Page Code Behind (C#)**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "N/A";
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var svc = new HelloWorldMSTSoapClient("HelloWorldMSTSoap"))
    {
        if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "1")
         {
            Label1.Text = svc.HelloWorld1();
         }
         else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "2")
         {
            Label1.Text = svc.HelloWorld2();
         }
         else
         {
            Label1.Text = "N/A";
         }
    }
}
```

**Web.config (Service Model Section)** - you shouldn't need to add it manually as it's handled by VS by default.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HelloWorldMSTSoap" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="HelloWorldMSTSoap12">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://www.myshoptour.com/WebServices/HelloWorldMST.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HelloWorldMSTSoap"
        contract="HelloWorldMSTTest.HelloWorldMSTSoap" name="HelloWorldMSTSoap" />
      <endpoint address="http://www.myshoptour.com/WebServices/HelloWorldMST.asmx"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="HelloWorldMSTSoap12"
        contract="HelloWorldMSTTest.HelloWorldMSTSoap" name="HelloWorldMSTSoap12" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Outcome**

When `HelloWorld1` is selected

[image]

When `HelloWorld2` is selected

[image]

**Note**
For your convenience, here's the VB version of the code behind (converted by [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/))

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = "N/A"
End Sub

Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Using svc = New HelloWorldMSTSoapClient("HelloWorldMSTSoap")
        If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "1" Then
            Label1.Text = svc.HelloWorld1()
        ElseIf DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "2" Then
            Label1.Text = svc.HelloWorld2()
        Else
            Label1.Text = "N/A"
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: woodykiddy... thank you so much!  I got it to work.  The only significant difference:

Comment: Originally:
Dim wsProd As New wsHelloWorldMSTprod.HelloWorldMSTSoapClient()
Your suggestion, that worked:
Dim wsProd As New wsHelloWorldMSTprod.HelloWorldMSTSoapClient("HelloWorldMSTSoap")

Comment: @NancyK Yes, that's correct. You need to specify which endpoint to go with. By default, VS automatically added two endpoints for the same contract, `HelloWorldMSTTest.HelloWorldMSTSoap`. Anyway, glad it helped. Please mark it if you are happy about the answer.

Comment: @NancyK a tick under the vote count? or if you can't mark it for now, you can also try the up-vote as well.

Comment: I did the tick mark, but it would not let me up-vote because I am such a newbie!  Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @NancyK no worries. Hope you enjoy SO and happy programming.